# Firebase cloud functions - Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, mailgun

I've read thru the other threads and tried to return something to my cloud functions, but it still gives the same Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value warning... What am I missing here?

Basically, I'm sending two emails out using mailgun-js to the user and to the admin, even though the sending is successful and stuff, I still get the same warning in my logs.

```
exports.sendSample = functions.database
.ref( 'sample/{pushID}' )
.onWrite( event => {

    //  only trigger if it's new
    if ( !event.data.exists() || event.data.previous.exists() ) return 0

    const e = event.data.val()

    const toUser = {
        to      : `${ e.email }`,
        from    : `xxx`,
        subject : `xxx`,
        html    : `xxx`
    }

    const toAdmin = {
        to      : `${ e.admin }`,
        from    : `xxx`,
        subject : `xxx`,
        html    : `xxx`
    }

    //  send sms
    if ( e.mobile !== 'none' ) {
        return client.messages.create({
            body : `xxx`,
            to   : `${e.mobile}`,
            from : `xxx`
        })
        .then( message => {
            sendEmail()
            return message.sid
        })
        .catch( err => {
            return err
        })
    } else {
        sendEmail()
    }

    //  send email
    function sendEmail() {
        if ( e.email !== 'none' ) {
            return mailgun.messages().send( toUser, ( err, body ) => {
                return ( err, body )
                return mailgun.messages().send( toAdmin, ( err, body ) => {
                    return ( err, body )
                })
            })
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you share the complete cloud function code ?

Comment: As Mark says: make sure that we can see the entire-but-minimal Cloud Functions code that reproduces the problem. Right now we're missing how you wire `sendEmail` up to Cloud Functions. But I immediately notice that you don't return anything when `e.email === 'none'`, which could be a problem.

Comment: I tried returning true when email === none, but it still results similarly.

@mark922 I'm updating the question with the full functions now.

Answer (score 2):

As already been said, you need to return a value.

```
if (e.email !== 'none') {
    ...
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but the results are still the same... The function runs successfully but a warning of undefined returned.

Comment: return sendEmail()

Comment: Alas, I thought "return sendEmail() " fixed the issue, but after a few days of successes... Today it returned the same warning again... Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value... Sigh... I already have everything attempting to return something, what else is missing? @4face

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
// send sms
if ( e.mobile !== 'none' ) {
  ...

} else {
    sendEmail()
}
```

to

```
// send sms
if ( e.mobile !== 'none' ) {
  ...

} else {
    return sendEmail()
}
```